# Запрос на связь ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, запрос

Есть 2 сущности:

```
public class Firm {
   private String name; 
}

public class Contractor {
   private Integer inn;
   @ManyToOne
   private Firm firm; 
}
```

Пытаюсь получить список фирм, у которых инн контрактора равен определенному числу. Будет приходить список инн (так что фирм может быть много).

Пока решил сделать для 1 инн. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
criteria.createAlias("contractor", "contr");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("contr.inn", inn));
```

И благополучно получаю exeption `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: contractor of: Firm`, что в принципе правильно.

Как сделать запрос, который мне нужен?

P.S. Запрос делать надо к таблице Firm.

Comment: Все таки, попробуйте и в классе фирмы определить связь с контракторами. Опять же из ваших аннотаций не вижу что такое INN - ключ или просто член-данное. В связи с этим возможны два случая связывания - если ключ, то OneToMany, если же у вас контрактор не сущность, а встраиваемый объект (Embeddable), то ElementCollection. С Criteria API не работал, тут подсказать не смогу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел ответ.   
Надо делать еще один подзапрос.   
С помощью  Criteria не получится, нужно использовать DetachedCriteria.
В моем случае запрос будет вот таким:

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Contractor.class, "cont");
dc.setProjection(Projections.property("firm"));
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("cont.inn",inn));
criteria.add(Property.forName("id").in(dc));
```

Вообще с помощью DetachedCriteria можно связать никак несвязанные таблицы.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это запрос к сущностям, которые не привязаны к какому-либо контексту (detached).

Comment: @smackmychi вроде да, другого способа на нашел, просто изменять сущности я уже не могу, т.е. не внести ссылку на контрактора в фирму.

Comment: @whispeer ошибки проектирования?

Comment: скорее всего, я недавно этот проект начал дорабатывать, возможно сам где-то недопонял.

Comment: @whispeer нет варианта перекачать все в другую базу, исправив сущности как надо?

Comment: @smackmychi в недалеком будущем да, ) а пока надо наработать некоторую функциональность сервиса, так сказать по-быстрому. Кто же не грешил костылями?)

Comment: @whispeer дело не столько в костыле, сколько в вообще наличии сущности с единственным полем, причем еще и без всяких связей.